# Can't hide iOS Keyboard (xcode 5) in current project

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode5

Xcode 5 / iOS 7.

This problem has been driving me crazy for the better part of a day now.  In my current project, I'm unable to hide the iOS keyboard using resignFirstResponder.  However, strangely, I am able to get this to work in all other projects I'm currently working on.  Code below.  Thanks so much, guys!

**ViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>
{    
    IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *selectcontrolNumbers;
    IBOutlet UILabel *output;
    int grossNetVar;
    double calcVariable;
    IBOutlet UIButton *hideConvertNet;
    IBOutlet UIButton *hideConvertGross;

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *dollarTextField;
@property (nonatomic)int grossNetVar;
@property (nonatomic) double calcVariable;
- (IBAction)selectAction:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)convertToNet:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)convertToGross:(id)sender;
@end
```

**ViewController.m:**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize grossNetVar;
@synthesize calcVariable;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.dollarTextField.delegate = self;
}

-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    [self.dollarTextField resignFirstResponder];
}


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (IBAction)selectAction:(id)sender {

    if (selectcontrolNumbers.selectedSegmentIndex == 0){
        grossNetVar = 1;
    } else {
        grossNetVar = 2;
    }

    if (grossNetVar == 1) {
        hideConvertGross.enabled = YES;
        hideConvertNet.enabled = NO;
    } else {
        hideConvertGross.enabled = NO;
        hideConvertNet.enabled = YES;
    }
}

- (IBAction)convertToNet:(id)sender {
    NSString *textFieldText = _dollarTextField.text;
    calcVariable = .85;
    double dollarTotal = [textFieldText doubleValue];
    double netCalc = calcVariable * dollarTotal;

    NSString *netString = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"The NET total is %g", netCalc];
    output.text = netString;

}

- (IBAction)convertToGross:(id)sender {
}

@end
```

Comment: Is `-(void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event` being called?

Comment: Yes - right below viewDidLoad

Comment: As @nhgrif pointed out, put a breakpoint there and see if it's called or not.

Comment: check userInteraction property of your view in xib/storyboard? Do you have any image view on top of view?

Comment: @MrShickadance9 So you don't understand what I asked at all.

Comment: @nhgrif I misread what you wrote - apologies.  It is not being called.

Comment: The weird thing is that I literally copied and pasted the code into a new project, and the method is being called fine.  Could I simply use the other project?  Of course.  However, I want to try to use this as a learning opportunity since I'm newer to this.

Comment: `touchesBegan:withEvent:` is a `UIView` method. It will obviously not be called in a view controller. Please check your code.

Comment: @duci9y not sure what to say.  It's working just fine in my other project, also ViewController.  This seems to be what nhgrif and mostruash recommend.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. You need to sort out your responder chain. I suggest you research a bit on that, and check if you have the right responder chain for your job.

Comment: I figured it out.  The view in the viewcontroller was set as UIControl not UIView.  Thanks for everyone's help.  As someone who is just getting into this, it's much appreciated, even when some people seem to have woken up on the wrong side of the bed :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using a toolbar (you can drag one on to the screen into the storyboard) that only appears when the keyboard is opened, and put a done button on that. Create an IBAction for the touchdown of that button in which you can do

```
 [donebutton resignFirstResponder];
```